# Using foreign keys in a SQL table

Tags: sql, key

I'm trying to reference a foreign key in a table to reference the primary key of another in order to get an attribute from that table. I think I worded that right.

It looks more obvious what I"m trying to do when you look at the code.

```
 SELECT PATIENT_T.FIRST_NAME, PATIENT_T.LAST_NAME, TREATMENT_TYPE 
 FROM TREAMENT;
```

Where `Patient_T` is another table, where the primary key is `PATIENT_ID`.

`Treatment` is the table I'm searching from, where `Treatment_ID` is the primary key of that, and treatment type is another attribute.

`Treatment` has `PATIENT_ID` as a foreign key, so I thought that meant I could reference the first and last name by some sort of reference.

Did I type it wrong or how exactly do i do this?

Comment: Is there a way of joining 4 tables?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You should join tables to get data from multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
SELECT PATIENT_T.FIRST_NAME, PATIENT_T.LAST_NAME, TREATMENT_TYPE FROM TREAMENT
LEFT JOIN Patient_T.PATIENT_ID = TREAMENT.PATIENT_ID
```